# Agregar columnas a partir de valores de una fila SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Es posible organizar fechas en columnas  agrupando por nombres.
Existen nombres repetitivos con 1 dia o 2 etc.
Al agrupar como es posible sumar esos días y distribuir fecha de dias en fecha1, fecha2 y fecha3
Gracias por cualquier apoyo o asesoría.
Saludos!

CODIGO

```
WITH EventosNumerados AS (SELECT Fk_Usuario, cantidadDias, FechaInicio,Fk_TipoEvento,
                             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Fk_Usuario ORDER BY FechaInicio ASC)AS orden
                      FROM Eventos
                      WHERE Eventos.Fk_TipoEvento = 3 AND YEAR(FechaInicio) = YEAR (GETDATE()))
           
     


   SELECT EN.Fk_Usuario,U.NOMBRE + ' ' + U.APELLIDOPATERNO + ' ' + U.APELLIDOMATERNO AS Nombre,

   3 - SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR,FechaInicio,GETDATE())=0 AND  Fk_TipoEvento= 3 THEN cantidadDias ELSE  NULL END) AS 'DiasDisponibles',
   
   MIN(CASE WHEN orden = 1 AND  Fk_TipoEvento= 3 THEN FechaInicio ELSE NULL END) AS 'Fecha 1',

   MIN(CASE WHEN orden = 1 AND  Fk_TipoEvento= 3 AND cantidadDias=2 THEN DATEADD(DAY,1,FechaInicio)
            WHEN orden = 1 AND  Fk_TipoEvento= 3 AND cantidadDias=3 THEN DATEADD(DAY,1,FechaInicio)
            WHEN orden = 2 AND  Fk_TipoEvento= 3 AND cantidadDias=1 THEN FechaInicio END) AS 'Fecha 2',
  
  MIN(CASE WHEN orden = 1 AND  Fk_TipoEvento= 3 AND cantidadDias=3 THEN DATEADD(DAY,2,FechaInicio)
            WHEN orden = 3 AND  Fk_TipoEvento= 3 AND cantidadDias=1 THEN FechaInicio 
            --WHEN orden = 2 AND cantidadDias=1  THEN 
            -- CASE WHEN orden = 1 and Fk_TipoEvento= 3 AND cantidadDias=2 THEN FechaInicio END  
             END) AS 'Fecha 3'
FROM EventosNumerados AS EN
FULL JOIN USUARIO AS U ON U.USUARIOID = EN.Fk_Usuario
GROUP BY EN.Fk_Usuario, U.NOMBRE, U.APELLIDOPATERNO, U.APELLIDOMATERNO;
```

Esto Obtengo... Es correcto pero ciertos parametros no los puedo insertar en fila(Ejemplo Fk_Usuario 58)("Esta comentado posible opcion, no me funciona"):

| Fk_Usuario | Nombre | DiasDisponibles | Fecha1 | Fecha2 | Fecha3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 45 | SALVADOR CAMACHO SERRATO | 0 | 2021-05-02 00:00:00.000 | 2021-05-04 00:00:00.000 | 2021-05-07 00:00:00.000 |
| 49 | FERNANDA OLVERA CASTELLANOS | 1 | 2021-07-15 00:00:00.000 | 2021-07-16 00:00:00.000 | null |
| 50 | MARÍA ELISA DIAZ ALCAZAR | 2 | 2021-08-05 00:00:00.000 | null | null |
| 58 | JESUS ANTONIO ARMENTA ZAZUETA | 0 | 2021-06-07 00:00:00.000 | 2021-06-08 00:00:00.000 | null(error deberian ser 3dias) |
| 75 | TANIA CECILIA VALENZUELA BOJORQUEZ | 1 | 2021-05-03 09:00:00.000 | 2021-05-04 09:00:00.000 | null |

TABLA DE CONSULTA:

| Fk_TipoEvento | Fk_Usuario | FechaInicio | FechaFin | CantidadDias |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 45 | 2021-05-02 00:00:00.000 | 2021-05-03 00:00:00.000 | 1 |
| 3 | 45 | 2021-05-04 00:00:00.000 | 2021-05-05 00:00:00.000 | 1 |
| 3 | 45 | 2021-05-07 00:00:00.000 | 2021-05-08 00:00:00.000 | 1 |
| 1 | 45 | 2021-05-31 00:00:00.000 | 2021-06-02 00:00:00.000 | 2 |
| 3 | 58 | 2021-06-07 00:00:00.000 | 2021-06-09 00:00:00.000 | 2 |
| 3 | 58 | 2021-06-21 00:00:00.000 | 2021-06-22 00:00:00.000 | 1 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

...

Comment: Si, es posible. En los `CASE` de la primer query tines que usar funciones de agregación (COUNT, MIN, MAX, etc) para las columnas cantidadDias y FechaInicio, porque estás agrupando por otras columnas.

Comment: No es posible por ejemplo: 
La fila 4, 5 y 6 son repetidas.
Al agrupar sumaria 3 dias por tanto no se distribuirian en fecha1, fecha2 y fecha3

Comment: si, ya corregí pregunta, no tengo mucho conocimiento sql, error planteamiento mío

Comment: Pega la query como texto, no la imagen, así puedo trabajar sobre la misma,

Comment: Ahí subí una repsuesta, no me queda claro si usas la misma fecha para cada columna o respetas la de cada fila (yo opte por este último caso).

Comment: Erick te ha servido mi respuesta?  Veo que has agregado otra pregunta parecida.  Si mi respuesta contestó tu pregunta marcala para que tu pregunta quede como contestada,  caso contrario dime cuál es el problema así las modifico.

Comment: Si, @nachospiu me ayudo avanzar mucho, 
me quedan variables sin resolver... por ejemplo lo comentando en codigo.
Anexo al final resultado y lineas comentadas

Comment: No me queda claro cual es el resultado final que querés obtener. Como te dijo @gbianchi en la otra pregunta, ayudaría mucho que publiques un conjunto reducido de datos de ejemplo (como están en la base de datos: 10 filas, un ejemplo que incluya fecha1, 2 y 3), y el resultado que quieres obtener a partir de ese ejemplo (arma el resultado a mano, como quedaría después de ejecutar la query). No agregues imágenes, así yo puedo copiar esos datos para probar.

Comment: He editado pregunta.. gracias amigo!

Comment: De nada @erick-paul! Creo que pude entender lo que estabas buscando, he editado mi respuestas y agregado una nueva query al final de la misma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que esta es la query que buscas:

Primero tienes que numerar los eventos, comenzando desde 1 para cada usuario (Fk_Usuario), para numerarlos yo los ordené según la fechaInicio ASC (desde la fecha mas chica a la mas grande). Luego en los `CASE` utilizas este orden. El `CASE` está dentro de la función de agregación MIN() ya que estoy agrupando por Fk_Usuario (tambien podría haber usado MAX() es indistinto en este caso).

```
WITH EventosNumerados AS (SELECT Fk_Usuario, cantidadDias, FechaInicio,
                                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Fk_Usuario ORDER BY FechaInicio ASC)AS orden
                          FROM Eventos
                          WHERE Eventos.Fk_TipoEvento = 3)
                       
                       
SELECT EN.Fk_Usuario,
       U.NOMBRE + ' ' + U.APELLIDOPATERNO + ' ' + U.APELLIDOMATERNO AS Nombre,
       count(cantidadDias),
       MIN(CASE WHEN orden = 1 THEN FechaInicio END) AS 'Fecha 1',
       MIN(CASE WHEN orden = 2 THEN DATEADD(DAY, 1, FechaInicio) END) AS 'Fecha 2',
       MIN(CASE WHEN orden = 3 THEN DATEADD(DAY, 2, FechaInicio) END) AS 'Fecha 3'
FROM EventosNumerados AS EN
INNER JOIN USUARIO AS U ON U.USUARIOID = EN.Fk_Usuario
GROUP BY EN.Fk_Usuario, U.NOMBRE, U.APELLIDOPATERNO, U.APELLIDOMATERNO;
```

**EDITADA**

Luego de que editaras la pregunta y agregaras datos de ejemplo y el resultado esperado puede entender mejor lo que estabas tratando de lograr.

Según entiendo cuando un registro tiene una cantidad de días mayor a 1 (FechaFin > FechaInicio + 1 día) quieres "desagregar" dicho intervalo. Utilicé una query recursiva para generar tantos registros como días haya dentro del intervalo, luego enumero las filas (comenzando desde 1 por cada usuario y ordenando por fecha) y luego pivoteo las tres primeras fechas utilizando la sentencia `CASE`:

```
WITH EventosDesplegados AS (SELECT Fk_Usuario, FechaInicio, FechaInicio AS Fecha
                            FROM Eventos
                            WHERE Fk_TipoEvento = 3
                            
                            UNION ALL
                            
                            SELECT e.Fk_Usuario, e.FechaInicio, DATEADD(DAY, 1, ed.Fecha)
                            FROM Eventos e
                            INNER JOIN EventosDesplegados ed ON e.Fk_Usuario = ed.Fk_Usuario AND 
                                                                 e.FechaInicio = ed.FechaInicio
                            WHERE Fk_TipoEvento = 3 AND DATEADD(DAY, 1, ed.Fecha) < e.FechaFin),

       EventosNumerados AS (SELECT Fk_Usuario, Fecha,
                              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Fk_Usuario ORDER BY Fecha ASC)AS orden
                       FROM EventosDesplegados)

SELECT Fk_Usuario,
       U.NOMBRE + ' ' + U.APELLIDOPATERNO + ' ' + U.APELLIDOMATERNO AS Nombre,
       3 - count(*) AS DiasDisponibles,
       MIN(CASE WHEN orden = 1 THEN Fecha END) AS 'Fecha 1',
       MIN(CASE WHEN orden = 2 THEN Fecha END) AS 'Fecha 2',
       MIN(CASE WHEN orden = 3 THEN Fecha END) AS 'Fecha 3'
FROM EventosNumerados AS EN
INNER JOIN USUARIO AS U ON U.USUARIOID = EN.Fk_Usuario
GROUP BY Fk_Usuario, U.NOMBRE, U.APELLIDOPATERNO, U.APELLIDOMATERNO;
```